# UIImagePickerController issue - iPhone

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using `UIImagePickerController` for capturing the photo in both `portrait` and `landscape` mode from camera, allowed orientation in my app is `portrait & landscape`. In portrait mode, my camera overlay is working fine. But with landscape mode, after capturing photo default camera overlay label "Preview" and use & retake action button and also the live image captured from the camera is coming in portrait mode. Should I need to use auto resizing.  How can I set this full camera overlay view (2nd screenshot) in landscape mode?

Here is my code to present `UIImagePickerController`:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO){
    NSLog(@"Camera not available");
    return;
}

imagePickerController.delegate = self;
imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

For orientation, here is my code for view controller class where i am using image picker controller..

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;  
}
```

here is my camera initial view, when my device is in landscape mode:

[image]

second view after capture photo from camera :

[image]

My view controller, where i am displaying image picker is only in portrait mode, but capturing photo from camera should work for portrait and landscape using image picker.  i want that in landscape mode, my camera overlay (attached second screenshot) should display their Preview label bar in the bottom of the view. Is it possible with default camera overlay or i need to create custom camera overlay view? Please help me to fix it. It is major problem in my app.

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't do that with "UIImagePickerController " [kindly take a look at documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html).

> Important: The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified, with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the cameraOverlayView property and use that view to present additional information or manage the interactions between the camera interface and your code.

But you can use the [Assets Library Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html) to access the list of images and create your own image picker.

You can also try a git : [ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController).

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code to fixe your Uiimage, you might have to tweak  it a little bit to get your own correct orientation,

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
 {
       UIImage *originalImage = (UIImage*) [info  objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    //--> get the fixed orientation image
  UIImage *fixedImage = [self fixOrientation:originalImage];


 }


- (UIImage *)fixOrientation:(UIImage*)takenImage {
// --> check the correct orientation if yes return the same.
if (takenImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return takenImage;

// --> if taken image orientation is wrong adjust the image as per the correct orientation.
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

switch (takenImage.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, takenImage.size.width, takenImage.size.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
        break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, takenImage.size.width, 0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
        break;

        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, takenImage.size.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -M_PI_2);
        break;
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
        break;
}

switch (takenImage.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, takenImage.size.width, 0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
        break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, takenImage.size.height, 0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
        break;
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        break;
}

//--> draw the calculated image above
CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, takenImage.size.width, takenImage.size.height,
                                         CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(takenImage.CGImage), 0,
                                         CGImageGetColorSpace(takenImage.CGImage),
                                         CGImageGetBitmapInfo(takenImage.CGImage));
CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);
switch (takenImage.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:

        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,takenImage.size.height,takenImage.size.width), takenImage.CGImage);
        break;

    default:
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,takenImage.size.width,takenImage.size.height), takenImage.CGImage);
        break;
}

// return the new fixed image to display
CGImageRef cgimg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
CGContextRelease(ctx);
CGImageRelease(cgimg);
return img;
}
```

you can adjust your code to get the desired orientation you want.

Comment: @spiderThanks,i have used your above code, but my problem is still same. I want my attached second screenshot comes in landscape instead of portrait.

Comment: Is it possible to skip second screenshot, i mean to say when user will tap on camera button of first screenshot, that time it will dismiss picker view(for skipping 2nd screenshot) and didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method will invoke..?

Comment: the above code is doing the same it is changing the orientation of your clicked image but by default what image orientation you want for that i have commented in the end that you will have to tweak the above code a little,rest  the funda is the same, for the UIimagecontroller @iLearner is correct you can't put it in landscape mode but you can change your image orientation to display correctly